# Properly compile Zim wiki for Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, compilation, wiki

Does anyone know how to compile [Zim wiki](http://zim-wiki.org) for Mac so that it functions just like any other app. I currently have it setup using Platypus as described [here](https://computableverse.com/blog/install-zim-wiki-macos-osx). However that gives you [two icons in the dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlDO3.png) and the [app window doesn't look very nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2k7l.png). I was wondering if there perhaps was a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wait is over, As of today the best way to use Zim with MacOS is as below. It works flawless even with Retina display support. It involves two simple steps.

- Step 1: Use Homebrew to install zim, which takes care of building by resolving all the proper dependencies. `brew install zim`
- Step 2: [Place a wrapper app](https://github.com/jaap-karssenberg/zim-desktop-wiki/files/1568387/Zim.zip) in the Applications folder which will be helpful in launching the app, and direct switching with apps like BetterTouchTool etc.

  Thanks to @izhakjakov for solving years log agony of not been able to use Zim. This link gives all the required information.

  https://github.com/jaap-karssenberg/zim-wiki/wiki/Mac-OSX-App-(wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

I had used a different method to compile Zim for my MacOS that involved ScriptEditor years ago.  Zim died on me recently after updates.  I was so relieved to find out how much simpler it is now.  This is similar to the above solution, just using Platypus. Thank you to @kaxing. These are his instructions -

Zim actually works pretty okay on macOS’ command lines:

```
$ brew install zim
$ zim
```

But natrually you want it on Dock, here is how to do it,

First, install Platypus, it’s a tool that wrapping scripts into native Mac app.

Second, download Zim source code

Now, open Platypus.app, configure as follow:

Add a new script copy/paste this into it:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH;../Resources/zim-desktop-wiki/zim"

/usr/local/bin/python3 ../Resources/zim-desktop-wiki/zim.py --standalone
```

Set Interface to "None" if you want to ignore console outputs

Then, drag the uncompressed source code folder for zim in Bundle Files, please do change the path name accordingly to the file you just downloaded.

Lastly hit the "Create App" button you are good to go

Visit his site for more information:
https://blog.kaxing.info/zim-app/